# How to create a HTML5 tag input

Tags: html

for my HTML5 web application (PHP) I need some input widget for tags like many modern tools have them. For example here a screenshot of Jira label list:

No idea how this widget type is named. I thought maybe it's possible to style with a HTML5 form? Any ideas? I tried to search in goggle, but "tag" and "html" together is a bad search combination. :-)

Hmmm, I just found out by reverse engineering the code of this web page from the tags input below I get some ideas...

But does anyone know an easier example?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXV28.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery autocompleter:
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

And style it whatever you want